# Is it necessary to make <listener-class> tag entry in web.xml even after adding @WebListener annotation to my listener class?

Tags: java, servlets, listener, httpsession

Is it necessary to make listener-class tag entry in web.xml even after adding @WebListener annotation to my listener class?

Because when I use just @WebListener annotation without making listener-class tag entry in web.xml, my listener class does not get executed.

When I use both the listener-class tag entry in web.xml and @WebListener for my listener class, then only my listener class is getting executed.

(*Additional info: java version "1.7.0_79" , Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15*)

Following is the listener-class tag entry in web.xml :

```html
<listener>
        <listener-class>  org.shan.jspservlets.CountUserListener </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Following is my listener class :

```html
package org.shan.jspservlets;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

@WebListener
public class CountUserListener implements HttpSessionListener {
 ServletContext ctx = null;
 static int total = 0, current = 0;

 public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent e) {
  total++;
  current++;

  ctx = e.getSession().getServletContext();
  ctx.setAttribute("totalusers", total);
  ctx.setAttribute("currentusers", current);

 }

 public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent e) {
  current--;
  ctx.setAttribute("currentusers", current);
 }

}
```

Comment: This will depend on the servlet API version supported by your web container (tomcat, jboss etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotations like `@WebServlet`, `@WebListener`, etc. were introduced in Servlet 3.0, so if you are using a servlet container with a servlet version < 3.0 the annotations are not processed.

Annotations are also not processed if the `web-app` element tells the container to ignore them:

```
<web-app metadata-complete="true" ...>
```

Then your annotated class must be either in `WEB-INF/classes`or in a jar in `WEB-INF/lib`, else the annotation is also ignored.